# When accessing array properties in laravel , i get an error . Why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following edit method in my laravel controller:

```
public function editArtilce(Request $request) {
        /* Get the last part of the URI */
        $explodedUrl = explode('/', $request->url());
        $urlSlug = array_pop($explodedUrl);

        $article = DB::table('admin')->where('slug', 'LIKE', '%' . $urlSlug . '%')->get();
        return $article;
}
```

Now since i am doing:

```
return $article;
```

I get the following output in the browser:

```
[{"id":10,"title":"This is a title","description":"This is a description","keywords":"Keyword1 , Keyword2 , Keyword3 , Keyword4 , Keyword5 , Keyword6","blog_content":"<p>I am a lovely burger<\/p>","tag":"gulp","filePath":"2017-02-23-21-54-30-blog-post-image.jpg","slug":"this-is-a-title","created_at":"2017-02-23 21:54:30","updated_at":"2017-02-23 21:54:30"},{"id":11,"title":"This is a title","description":"This is a description","keywords":"Keyword1 , Keyword2 , Keyword3 , Keyword4 , Keyword5 , Keyword6","blog_content":"<p>I am a lovely burger<\/p>","tag":"gulp","filePath":"2017-02-23-21-56-29-blog-post-image.jpg","slug":"this-is-a-title","created_at":"2017-02-23 21:56:29","updated_at":"2017-02-23 21:56:29"}]
```

But when i try to access the properties of this array like so:

```
return $article->title
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Why am i unable to access the properties of an array in laravel ? What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `first()` instead of `get()` to get the object directly.

```
$article = DB::table('admin')
             ->where('slug', 'LIKE', '%' . $urlSlug . '%')
             ->first();
```

and you have to check if it not null before trying access it's properties. `$article->title` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `$article->title` try:

```
$article[0]->title;
```

**as $article is a Std class object its structure is like:**

```
array(
    {  }  // 0th index
    {  }  // 1st index
)
```

To make it dynamic use `foreach()` like:

```
foreach($article as $data)
{
    $data->id;
    $data->title;
}
```